# JDK 11 JavaFX with Maven: can't add dependencies to project

Tags: maven, javafx, fxml, java-11

I used the sample archetype of openjfx to create a simple FXML base project from here: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven
I want to add other functionalities (such as parsing of xml files etc.) but when i try to use the added dependency, for some reason the objects are not recognized.

pom.xml:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.msd</groupId>
    <artifactId>MSDLog</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-xml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.msd.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

App.java file:
You can see that the XmlMapper is commented out since it does not recognize it

```
package org.msd;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {

    private static Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        scene = new Scene(loadFXML("environment"), 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    static void setRoot(String fxml) throws IOException {
        //------- THIS FAILS -------
        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();

        scene.setRoot(loadFXML(fxml));
    }

    private static Parent loadFXML(String fxml) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource(fxml + ".fxml"));
        return fxmlLoader.load();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Trying to import package:

[image: dependency]

Trying to "Add Maven dependency..." will suggest irrelevant packages

[image: Add Maven dependency]

What am i missing???

Comment: Maybe you have to add a "requires ..."-statement to the module-info.java?!

Comment: do i have to add requires to every library i want to add to the project there? maven is not enough?

Comment: If you have a modular project and you want to use an external library, you have to alter the module-info.java accordingly - Yes. It is not necessary for a non-modular project, because there you (can) remove the module file.